# Distinction between "ambulate" and "perambulate"?

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

At a cursory glance, these two terms appear to be synonyms.  But that would strike me as unusual since one is a prefixed form of the other.  (Prefixes are used to modify a word in a specific and consistent way.  As a result, the prefixed form of a word has a different meaning than the word.)

"[Per-](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/per-)" confers a quality of thoroughness or fullness.  But in the context of ambulation, this doesn't seem like a significant modifier (to me).

Am I wrong, or are "ambulate" and "perambulate" synonyms?

Comment: A quick lookup shows that `perambulate` can have the additional connotation of "for pleasure and in a leisurely way". For me it has the feeling of walking while taking in one's surrounding (in alignment with the "per" prefix), whereas ambulate is just a way to get from point A to point B.

Comment: @tcovo Can you provide a link to where you found that definition?

Comment: An important difference not mentioned in answers so far is that without the word *perambulate* we would not have the word *[pram](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=pram)*, a shortening of *perambulator*.

Comment: @cheeken I got that definition from a [Google search result](http://www.google.ca/search?q=perambulate), which [apparently](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/perambulation.aspx) [uses](http://searchengineland.com/google-dictionary-switched-to-oxford-pocket-dictionary-48258) the Oxford Pocket Dictionary of Current English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you are wrong.

To *ambulate* is to move by means of walking, parallel to the way *brachiate* means to move by means of swinging with your arms from hold to hold.

To *perambulate* is to walk through, or to traverse, something.  *Perambulate* therefore can take an object to be traversed.  You can "ambulate idly all afternoon", but rather than "perambulating idly all afternoon"; you should "perambulate the yard idly", or some such thing.

Comment: At least [one source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perambulate) disagrees, offering an intransitive version of *perambulate*.

Comment: According to Dictionary.com, [perambulate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perambulate) can be used with or without an object.  Do you have a different source that disagrees?

Comment: So noted.  I should scroll down the dictionary.com page further sometimes.  :-)  Post updated to indicate that it *can* take an object, rather than *must*.

Comment: MW offers _traverse_ as a synonym of [perambulate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perambulate), and _walk_ as a synonym of [ambulate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambulate), but does not list them as synonyms of each other.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot show any evidence for this but I suspect that *perambulate* does not use the prefix *per-* meaning *through*, but instead a shortening of the prefix *peri-* meaning *about* (Greek περί but also used in Latin).

Every case I know of *perambulate* suggests returning to the starting point, either wandering around (i.e. without a destination) for the purpose of exercise and fresh air (hence *pram*) or surveying boundaries by walking them.

Comment: I'm not convinced about *peri-*, but I agree *perambulate* invariably means walk **about** *(nearby: promenade/stroll, then return)*. Added to which it used to be quite common - but now it's positively dated. And *ambulate*, which used to be vanishingly rare, is now standard usage in the medical/physiotherapy context.